# Why is Chrome Dev Tools showing base64 in Rendered Fonts?

Tags: css, google-chrome-devtools, webfonts

I have the following CSS rule:

```
some-selector {
    font-family: 'Open Sans', 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
}
```

This shows up correctly as `font-family: 'Open Sans', 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif` in Chrome Dev Tools 'Computed' tab. Open Sans is loaded from the network in this case, and is applied correctly.

However in Dev Tools "Rendered Fonts" section I see

```
Cg7UAidtBkOtUziULXjeaA== — 8 glyphs
```

What does this mean?
I haven't used `data:` for a font anywhere, so I am not sure where did the base64 come from.

Comment: Are you using Google Fonts to import that font?